# how to see what supervisord configuration is used

Tags: supervisord

According to the documentation (http://supervisord.org/configuration.html), Supervisor will use the first file it finds.

1) $CWD/supervisord.conf
2) $CWD/etc/supervisord.conf
3) /etc/supervisord.conf

I am comparing two machines, they both do not have `/etc/supervisord.conf`.

However, for one of them, running the following works no matter where I run the command from:

```
sudo supervisorctl status
```

Could there be another setting or environment variable?

How could I find what config file it actually uses when it runs? Is there a verbose mode?

I am confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check the process listing:

```
$ ps aux | grep supervisor
root      1751  0.0  2.4  53668 12364 ?        Ss   01:41   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

Comment: The result is the same on both machines. I can see that supervisorctl is run without a configuration file but obviously on the machine 1, it still picks up my configuration file by default and I do not understand why.. I would like the same behavior on machine 2 but I cannot reproduce it if I do not know why it does that on machine 1.

Comment: I understood what was going on on machine 1. More info here: https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/issues/498 I asked on the repo whether this is a bug or I misunderstood the doc. Thanks again.